# Cantonese comedy cartoons

Tags: cantonese

I'd like to start watching either Cantonese series or western series dubbed in Cantonese to improve my language level. Do you have some suggestions? I like comedy cartoons like the Simpsons or Family Guy, but these don't seem to be dubbed in Cantonese.

Comment: If you want to watch the catonese about the family, I would suggest  大头儿子和小头爸爸，可可可心一家人 and 大耳朵图图

Comment: Wouldn't Cantonese cartoons 'subbed' in English a better way since you listen and understand from the subtitle?

Comment: @Whhhhhhhhy Are these also suited for adults? I mean I'd like it to be interesting for me to keep going

Comment: @Alex Yes that would be great too, but the few cantonese cartoons I found were primarily aimed at children

Comment: @J.Doe Sorry,I made a mistake, I mixed up the cartoon and Cantonese

Comment: @J.Doe I googled 'Cantonese anime with English Sub' and found a few - chances are there are far less with dubbed in Cantonese.  Also try anime instead of cartoon, as cartoon is almost always for kids, where anime can be anything.

Comment: @Alex Ah indeed I found way more things when searching for animed dubbed in cantonese instead ! Thanks !

Comment: @J.Doe That's good to know, enjoy!

Comment: Do you know http://www.opensubtitles.org to download free subtitles?

Answer (score 2):

Ohhh! Cartoons is my favorite. Let's me answer it!
I made a list for you first.

A.Comedy cartoons

1
我們這一家（My family）
MY childhood! Sooo adorable mum,a pretty body shape and humor to deal with any problems. A traditional Japanese family, nevertheless not too serious and rigid, and too much fun with them.

2
麥兜（McDull）
It's a original Hong Kong cartoon. About the dailylife of cute pig ! But honestly he speaks too little dialogue. And a lot of word about Hong Kong culture. I worry you canˊt understand so I put it no.2. It doesn't mean it is a bad cartoon. If you live in Hong Kong, you always find something similar with McDull.(maybe building, maybe food, maybemaybe activities )

3
多啦a夢（Doraemon）
It's a famous cartoon, no introduction.
However,
If you were to get a Doraemon, please wouldn't hesitate to share with me. I will appreciate it very much.

4
日式麵包王(Yakitate!! Japan）
That's funny story about a juvenile making amazing Japanese bread. 
↓↓↓↓The first episode↓
:(

5
小倩（Xiaoqian）
Human and Ghost Love(don't know how to translate)
小倩
[小倩](https://youtu.be/6t%20Df33HXAvk)

6 忍者亂太郎
Ninja's school daily

7 keroro軍曹
A frog wants to occupy the earth.

8
成語動畫廊
Awesome cartoon! Learn both  Chinese idioms and Chinese history.
I get lot of fun with it when I am primary school, becaue it means our Chinese teacher ask for leave and we can have a rest in a lesson.

成語動畫廊
[成語動畫廊](https://youtu.be/txjhGVoXKSI)

B.Adventure cartoon
1龍珠(Dragon Ball)
It is difficult to find Cantonese version on Youtube. Maybe search on tudou.com or youku.com

C Horror animation

1
死亡筆記（Death Note）
Please don't write down your name.

2
HunterXHunter(全職獵人)
Father where are u! I am your son.
There are two version of it.
Old version is easy to find Cantonese.
↓
:(

HOPPING THE ANSWER WON'T BE LATE FOR HELPING U! HAVE A NICE STUDY TOUR!